# How to initialize session and use them properly in JSP?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following files: **login.jsp**, **HomeController.java** and **DatabaseService.java** in my Spring MVC application. When someone click login button in **login.jsp** it transfer data (username, and password) to **HomeController.java**, then **HomeController.java** call the **DatabaseService.java** with some criteria and get response from it, and finally return the response to **login.jsp**. So far it is OK for invalid username and password field. Problem occurs when username and password in **login.jsp** matches with stored username and password.
The problem is, no data stores into the session variables/objects. I have tried several ways:

```
public String dblogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    String response = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    String pass = "", fname = "", lname = "";
    int userid = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bloodspring", "root", "");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            String query = "SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname, pword FROM bld_user WHERE uname='"+ username +"'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            int res = 0;
            while( rs.next() ) {
                res++;
                pass = rs.getString("pword");
                fname = rs.getString("user_fname");
                lname = rs.getString("user_lname");
                userid = rs.getInt("user_id");
            }
            if( res == 0 ) {
                response = "Invalid Username";
            } else {
                //String new_pass = crypt.encryption(password);
                if( crypt.encryption(password).compareTo(pass) != 0 ) {
                    response = "Invalid username and/or password";
                    //response = "Original :" + pass + " :::: new : " + crypt.encryption(password);
                } else {
                    HttpServletRequest request;
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    session.setAttribute("fname", fname);
                    session.setAttribute("lname", lname);
                    session.setAttribute("username", username);
                    session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
                    response = "Login Successful";
                }
            }
        } catch( SQLException Ex) {
            Ex.printStackTrace();
            response = "Sorry something goes wrong with your MySQL query or server";
        }
    } catch( ClassNotFoundException E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        response = "Sorry no MySQL class found";
    }
    return response;
}
```

But it shows some **null pointer exception** related errors. Show I change code as follows:

```
public String dblogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    String response = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    String pass = "", fname = "", lname = "";
    int userid = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bloodspring", "root", "");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            String query = "SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname, pword FROM bld_user WHERE uname='"+ username +"'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            int res = 0;
            while( rs.next() ) {
                res++;
                pass = rs.getString("pword");
                fname = rs.getString("user_fname");
                lname = rs.getString("user_lname");
                userid = rs.getInt("user_id");
            }
            if( res == 0 ) {
                response = "Invalid Username";
            } else {
                //String new_pass = crypt.encryption(password);
                if( crypt.encryption(password).compareTo(pass) != 0 ) {
                    response = "Invalid username and/or password";
                    //response = "Original :" + pass + " :::: new : " + crypt.encryption(password);
                } else {
                    HttpServletRequest request = null;
                    try {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                        session.setAttribute("fname", fname);
                        session.setAttribute("lname", lname);
                        session.setAttribute("username", username);
                        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
                        response = "Login Successful";
                        //response = fname + " " + lname;
                    } catch( java.lang.NullPointerException lex ) {
                        lex.printStackTrace();
                        response = "Something Wrong";
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch( SQLException Ex) {
            Ex.printStackTrace();
            response = "Sorry something goes wrong with your MySQL query or server";
        }
    } catch( ClassNotFoundException E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        response = "Sorry no MySQL class found";
    }
    return response;
}
```

But it return response as "Something Wrong" [catch block of java.lang.NullPointerException]. If I change the code as follows:

```
public String dblogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    String response = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    String pass = "", fname = "", lname = "";
    int userid = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bloodspring", "root", "");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            String query = "SELECT user_id, user_fname, user_lname, pword FROM bld_user WHERE uname='"+ username +"'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            int res = 0;
            while( rs.next() ) {
                res++;
                pass = rs.getString("pword");
                fname = rs.getString("user_fname");
                lname = rs.getString("user_lname");
                userid = rs.getInt("user_id");
            }
            if( res == 0 ) {
                response = "Invalid Username";
            } else {
                //String new_pass = crypt.encryption(password);
                if( crypt.encryption(password).compareTo(pass) != 0 ) {
                    response = "Invalid username and/or password";
                    //response = "Original :" + pass + " :::: new : " + crypt.encryption(password);
                } else {
                    HttpServletRequest request = null;
                    try {
                        response = fname + " " + lname;
                    } catch( java.lang.NullPointerException lex ) {
                        lex.printStackTrace();
                        response = "Something Wrong";
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch( SQLException Ex) {
            Ex.printStackTrace();
            response = "Sorry something goes wrong with your MySQL query or server";
        }
    } catch( ClassNotFoundException E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        response = "Sorry no MySQL class found";
    }
    return response;
}
```

Than it's work properly and return **first name**, **last name** from database. So I think my code is not correct for session.
Can anyone tell me how can I store data from database into session.

Comment: Is it a requirement to build the authentication on your own? If not, give spring security a try. Regarding the npe: Where is it thrown? Show the stacktrace.

Comment: You're calling getSession() on a null request object.( HttpServletRequest request = null;
                    try {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Comment: dsp_user: `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` is used very first I wrote those code. But it did not work.

Comment: @Shimul  have you tried the answer ? It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spring-security for authentication purpose. Apart from that you can follow the, following code snippet. Please note that you dont really need to store all the fields individually in session. All you need to store a user object into the session.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public ModelAndView post(@ModelAttribute("login") LoginEntity login, HttpServletRequest req) {


    /*    CHECK IN DATABASE if the user name and password matches or not */
    UserObject userObject=dblogin(login.userName,login.password);


    if(userObject!=null){
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("user",userObject);
    }
    else
       return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
```